# Determine values higher than twice minimum value in a list

Tags: loops, iteration, min

I have a large list with price data per 15 minutes over a whole year (total 35140 entries) (name list: p_avg_15). For the data, I need to determine per full week which entries have a price higher than twice the minimum price of that week.

Thus, per week I need to determine:
1 what the minimum price is for that week
2 which prices in that week are more than twice the minimum price

I then want to create a list in which only the prices that suffice the conditions are shown. For the other prices, a NaN value should be given.

I have tried to use a for loop and definition which looks like:

```py
def sel(p_avg_15):
    for i in p_avg_15:
            if i in p_avg_15 > 2 * min(i):
                return True
            else:
                return False
    
print(sel(p_avg_15))
```

However, the code does not work